# How to get a database and connect to it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm very new to all of this web stuff, and I'm pretty young, too, so I'm not great at this. I know PHP and I can make login forms with text files, I really badly want to expand to SQL, I've used SQL before on localhost XAMPP, but how would I create a free database that would work over FTP? Sorry about asking this, but I've searched for ages and found absolutely nothing. I'm connecting to my website "hughchalmers.com", via FTP, and I have no idea how to get SQL on it. Any answers or links are really greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Assuming your website is hosted by a 3rd party hosting company, you need to look at their help pages to see how to setup/configure a database; unless you have full control of the hosting server you cannot usually do it yourself from scratch.

Comment: I can ONLY upload via FTP, there is no control panel or anything.

Comment: A database (usually) requires a database server. It is not just s few files you can upload somehow. You need your service provider to provide such server. Or, alternatively, you could get your own system, a virtual server just for yourself, _then_ you can do whatever you want on that, for example configure a database server like MySQL and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a MySQL or another database server, if your hosting doesn't allow this, you can use free sites such as https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/

Comment: im currently using this to host a live mysql from a local server and it works great

Comment: I have my details, but how do I connect to it remotely? I'm trying from apache localhost

Comment: As an usual MySQL connection, write sqlX.domain.com instead of localhost and enter your details

Comment: <?php mysql_connect("sql1.blah.com","sql12345","password"); mysql_select_db("sql12345");